# Implementing a generic node

Tags: java, binary-tree, nodes

I keep receiving an error when I'm trying to implement a node with generic data types. the node must be able to take an int input as well as a fraction input. what am i doing wrong? The compiler says that "method Node(A) is undefined for class BinarySearchtree

```
    //creates a generic binary search tree class
public class BinarySearchTree<A> {

    //the root of the node, which is the middle value
    Node root;

    //this constructor will add a node
    public void addNode(A userNumber){

        Node<A> newNode = Node<A>(A userNumber);

    }//end addNode





    public class Node<T>{
        //this generic variable will become the user input either int or fraction
        private T number;

        //nodes that will become the left of right child of a parent node
        Node<T> leftChild;
        Node<T> rightChild;

        //a node constructor that will take a generic input
        Node(T number){
            this.number = number;
        }//end node constructor
    }//end the Node class



}//end binary search tree
```

Comment: Can you please post the error message? They are very descriptive and will tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Why are you not specifying the T for Node in Node root? I doubt it's OK in Java, though I don't remember it 100%.

Comment: Maybe you do not need to use generics as Integer and Double both Extend Number

Comment: You forgot the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
    Node<A> newNode = Node<A>(A userNumber);
```

use

```
    Node<A> newNode = new Node<A>(A userNumber);
```

You don't have any method Node which the compiler gladly tells you about.

Comment: oh my goodness, how could i forget the "new". such a simple mistake, thank you so much, im still pretty new to coding